# getting data in div based on dynamic dropdown and calculating dates

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Posting this question the second time. Hope I will get some required answers.

well, I am new to PHP. and I know this is a naive question but I am facing two issues.

1) I am supposed to display data of the field `'display_duration'` in div based on the selected option value(the select box options are fetched from the field 'priority' in the table). when the user clicks on say select option ' high' then the duration (3-4 weeks )  should be displayed in Div.

and my second problem is a calculation of dispatched and arrival dates and showing their results in separate div tags. The format should be `'01-Jan-2017'(dd-MMM-yyyy)`.

```
arrival date = current date+arrival_interval_days(a field given in table);
```

same goes for the calculation of dispatch date.
arrival and dispatch date calculation is also based on the selected priority option.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change the function in order.php class

```
public function checkduration($priority_id)
    {
        $result       = $this->db->query("SELECT priority_id, display_duration,dispatch_interval_days,arrival_interval_days FROM tblpriority WHERE priority_id='" . $priority_id . "'");
        $priorityData = $result->fetchAll();

        return $priorityData;
    }
```

And, In ajax call() php file should be as below.

```
<?php

use Cosmo\ConfigSettings;
use Cosmo\DAL\Order;

//End
//Application/DB Configuration
$config   = ConfigSettings::getInstance();
$basePath = $config->getBasePath();
//End

$response = [];

if (!empty($_REQUEST["priority_id"])) {
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    $priority_id                        = $_REQUEST['priority_id'];
    $addUser                            = new Order();
    $priorityData                       = $addUser->checkduration($priority_id);
    $response['display_duration']       = '';
    $response['dispatch_interval_days'] = '';
    $response['arrival_interval_days']  = '';
    if (!empty($priorityData)) {
        $response['display_duration']       = $priorityData[0]['display_duration'];
        $response['dispatch_interval_date'] = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData[0][dispatch_interval_days]} days"), time());
        $response['arrival_interval_date']  = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData[0][arrival_interval_days]} days"), time());
    }
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

Now you have all the data to display in client side with calculated arrival and dispatch date in format(1-Jan-2018)

And also added 2 divs for arrival and dispatch and populated the ajax response value by priority.

```
<?php
use Cosmo\ConfigSettings;
use Cosmo\DAL\Order;

//End
//Application/DB Configuration
$config = ConfigSettings::getInstance();




$priority_list_data = new Order();
$priority_data = $priority_list_data->getPriorityList();
$priority_option = '<option value=""></option>';
if ($priority_data != false) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($priority_data); $i++) {
        $priority_option .= '<option value= "' . $priority_data[$i]['priority_id'] . '" >' . $priority_data[$i]['priority'] . '</option>';
    }
}
?>


<div class="panel-body">
    <span class="pull-left">Priority:</span>
    <select class="form-control" id="priority_selected">>
        <?php echo $priority_option; ?>
    </select>
    <div class="small" id="priority_duration" ></div>

    <div class="small" id="arrival_date" ></div>
    <div class="small" id="dispatch_date" ></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // code to get all records from table via select box
        $("#priority_selected").change(function() {
            var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
            var dataString = 'priority_id='+ id;
            $.ajax({
                url: '_getEmployee.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(employeeData) {
                    if(employeeData) {
                        $("#priority_duration").html(employeeData.display_duration);
                        $("#arrival_date").html(employeeData.arrival_interval_date);
                        $("#dispatch_date").html(employeeData.dispatch_interval_date);

                    } else {

                        $("#priority_duration").hide();

                    }
                }
            });
        })
    });


</script>
```

Comment: 'Fatal error</b>: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\cosmo\App\orders\_getEmployee.php
thank you so much ....but got this Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cosmo\App\orders\_getEmployee.php'                                   got this error.  the error is ' $response['display_duration']       = $priorityData[0]['display_duration'];' in this line.

Comment: Please access from object instead of array, hope it solves your problem.

Comment: sir. changed the following code still no luck..                                                                                 $response['display_duration']       = $priorityData->display_duration;
        $response['dispatch_interval_days'] = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData->dispatch_interval_days} days"), time());
        $response['arrival_interval_days']  = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData->arrival_interval_days} days"), time());

Comment: tried this: $data = json_decode($response, true); as well.. but no luck. thank you.

Comment: can you please var_dump $priorityData?

Comment: Got nothing. No result. Thank you for helping sir.

Comment: That means query is not returning data, Can you please make sure the query returns data based on priority_id?

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much sir. I tried var_dump and then I echo out the query and got the query , then I run that query in my database and got the coreect result.  That means that the query is correct. But I am still getting the stdclass issue. Thank you once again. Any other suggestions?

Comment: after doing var_dump($priority_id); and var_dump($priorityData); and echo, I got this.                 SELECT priority_id, display_duration,dispatch_interval_days,arrival_interval_days FROM tblpriority WHERE priority_id='1'string(1) "1"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#10 (4) {
    ["priority_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["display_duration"]=>
    string(9) "4-6 Weeks"
    ["dispatch_interval_days"]=>
    int(40)
    ["arrival_interval_days"]=>
    int(55)
  }
}

Fatal error:Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in _getEmployee.php:39

Comment: changed the code:         $response['display_duration']       = $priorityData[0]->display_duration;
        $response['dispatch_interval_date'] = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData[0]->dispatch_interval_days}" ), time());
        $response['arrival_interval_date']  = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData[0]->arrival_interval_days} "), time());

Comment: Changed the code, and got this:<b>Warning</b>:date() expects at most 2 parameters,3 given in <b>_getEmployee.php</b> on line <b>40</b>
<b>Warning</b>:date() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in <b>_getEmployee.php</b> on line <b>41</b> {"display_duration":"3-4 Weeks","dispatch_interval_days":"","arrival_interval_days":"","dispatch_interval_date":false,"arrival_interval_date":false,"json":"{\"display_duration\":\"3-4 Weeks\",\"dispatch_interval_days\:\"\",\"arrival_interval_days\":\"\",\"dispatch_interval_date\":false,\"arrival_interval_date\":false}"}

Comment: changed the code a bit more $response['dispatch_interval_date'] = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData[0]->dispatch_interval_days}" ));
     $response['arrival_interval_date']  = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData[0]->arrival_interval_days} "));

Comment: and got this:{"display_duration":"4-6 Weeks","dispatch_interval_days":"","arrival_interval_days":"","dispatch_interval_date":"12-Dec-2017","arrival_interval_date":"11-Dec-2017","json":"{\"display_duration\":\"4-6 Weeks\",\"dispatch_interval_days\":\"\",\"arrival_interval_days\":\"\",\"dispatch_interval_date\":\"12-Dec-2017\",\"arrival_interval_date\":\"11-Dec-2017\"}"}      and still didn't get the values in div tags

Comment: okay, so made few changes and getting the result but the calculated dates are not correct. @mirza I am updating the code in my question. kindly,guide me. thank you.

Comment: Add `days` string in strtotime function as Change `$response['dispatch_interval_days'] = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData[0]->dispatch_interval_days}" ));
        $response['arrival_interval_days']  = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData[0]->arrival_interval_days} "));`       to                
     `$response['dispatch_interval_days'] = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData[0]->dispatch_interval_days} days" ));
        $response['arrival_interval_days']  = date('j-M-Y', strtotime("+{$priorityData[0]->arrival_interval_days} days"));`

Comment: I got the answer sir.. solved that already. Made few more changes. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: If you got my answer is useful, Please vote and acknowledge @alisonrusso .

Comment: I tried but wasn't able to vote your answer. Maybe , i am not allowed to. Really very  sorry...  What if i want normal to be default selected value and show it's result in div tags as default ?

Comment: @alisonrusso no problem, you can do so while generating the html, fetch the default values from DB or you can hardcode whichever you want.

Comment: fetching the default value from DB will only get me the default value not the calculated one. And I tried using option attribute selected but no help.

Comment: Remove this empty `$priority_option = '<option value=""></option>';` option will get the default option as first one.

Comment: Did that as well. But I am not getting div values. **Normal** is selected as default but there are no values in div. @mirza and Thanks sir for helping me.It would be great if you could help me a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

There should be change in jquery

```
$("#priority_duration").text(employeeData.display_duration);
```

This line should be replaced with

```
 $("#priority_duration").html(employeeData.display_duration);
```

You are returning `true` or `false` for the dropdown options so it will get only true instead you need to `response data` and instead of `equals to(==)` it should be `(!== 0)` please check and let me know if I am wrong.

```
public function checkduration($priority_id){
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT priority_id, display_duration FROM tblpriority WHERE priority_id='".$priority_id."'");
    $is_priority  = $result->fetchAll();
    if(count($is_priority)!== 0){
        //return true;
        //Here instead of return true you need to pass the data what you get in response
        return $is_priority;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

For the second answer.

If you are calculating arrival date from current_date+interval given in a table, the date will daily be changed, if you are not updating the interval. it will always be extended to next date. with an interval of given duration in table